# Getting error on running the Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am learning about servlets and JSP files and following the tutorial in [link](https://o7planning.org/en/10169/java-servlet-tutorial) to have at least a basic understanding. But I am stuck at the beginning of the tutorial when servlet has to be run on Tomcat. I am getting the following error:

[image: Error snippet]

Can anyone please tell if there is something I need to do to run Tomcat without this error?

Comment: open up command prompt and type in `java -version`. What do you see?

Comment: your eclipse tomcat configuration is wrong. Eclipse doesn't found it and report that in the console: I suggest you to check server installation directory.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte The java version it is showing is 1.8.0_181

Comment: @boly38 I also thought that but even when I have removed tomcat file and did the configuration again, it is still showing the same error

Comment: install tomcat distribution in a given directory an select the server configuration second option 'Use Tomcat installation...' specifying that directory. I already had issue with eclipse embedded Tomcat and I always use a dedicated Tomcat installation directory

Comment: @boly38 For some reason that section is 'greyed out'. That is, it is un selectable.

Comment: Your console is showing Tomcat-9.0.13 and Java 11. What version of Eclipse did you install?

Comment: @ujulu This is the Eclipse  version : Oxygen.1a(4.7.1a)

Comment: greyed: I am not using eclipse right now but I remember that the second option is available only just after creating the server instance.Try recreate it.

Comment: Have you solved the problem or still struggling?

Comment: @ujulu Solved it by reinstalling eclipse. Didn't do anything extra while re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not set up your environment correctly. I would suggest to use NetBeans IDE (with required services). While installing the IDE you will find option to install tomcat or glassfish server. After installing create a `Java Web->Java Web Application` project. All things should go perfect if you just run the project.

Comment: Can you please point me to any tutorial that does this in Eclipse EE ? Because of some constraints I cannot use NetBeans right now.